# Returning in between messages to the client using WCF services

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-client

I am developing an application based on simple WCF services, the client sends data to the server, the business logic in the client is staged, it either calls other process which are unique during  the initializing of different processes I need to send messages back to client without returning the actual control i.e. messages like

1. parameters initialized,
2. calculating the tax ,
3. creating report

etc

How am I able to do this?

Comment: What type of client do you have? Web, Windows...?

Comment: could be any one of them

Comment: How you solve this problem can very different depending on the capabilities of the client

Comment: as i have already told i want to return some message without returning the control to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [duplex binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx).

Comment: this works fine for returning the message through call back but at the same time it allows the client to continue processing which i do not want how can i stop the client's process until the server completes its job without using delay